# Get the response for more than 5 touches

Tags: iphone, multi-touch

I am writing one application which I am performing multi-touch operations.  I am able to do the operations up to 5 touches.  But I want to get the response for more than 5 touches.
Please guide me how to do it.

Comment: will you post the code

Comment: I think the iPhone supports 5 touches and the iPad 11.